# set default tab/page selection

Tags: polymer

I'm building a simple app, with a few tabs and pages linked to them.  I can get this to work fine, the problem is that there is no tab selected by default.

For example, I have a basic structure like this:

```
<paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{selected}}">
  <paper-tab data-route="1">Tab 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-route="2">Tab 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-route="3">Tab 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
  <div data-route="1">Page 1</div>
  <div data-route="2">Page 2</div>
  <div data-route="3">Page 3</div>
</iron-pages>
```

Works fine.  However when I open the page, none of the tabs are selected by default.  If I wanted this done, I could assign 'selected' to equal a specific value, such as:

```
<paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="1">
  <paper-tab data-route="1">TAB 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-route="2">TAB 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-route="3">TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

The problem with this is that then the tab/page binding doesn't work.

So, simple question, how do I keep the binding while also setting a default tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Polymer programming wraps these elements in a custom element representing the app (or some subsection of the app). Adding a `selected` property in the `properties` section of the surrounding element with a default value will set the default tab [Warning: Still a Polymer newbie]. Perhaps add something like:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'x-custom',

    properties: {
        selected: {
            value: 1
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you saying place the pages in a separate element or the tabs?  I'm still trying to wrap my head around nesting elements.  I can get it to work for simple displays but it's breaking on me when I try to route different views

Comment: Still doing some head wrapping myself. I'm saying all the app should be a custom element. `index.html` should be a minimal instantiation of element. This way, you have a `properties` section to put default bindings in, such as, the `selected` value here.

Comment: Ah yeah I get it now.  Placed the full header/tabs/pages in an element, which could then set the default value in the properties.  Pretty nifty once you get it working

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that ready function is the way to initialize !

```
ready: function() {
  this.selected = 0;
}
```

Use the properties solution if you want "selected" to be used outside of your component